# Fetch API failed to Fetch during authentication, alongside CORS error

Tags: node.js, npm, cors, jwt, koa

I have a button that lauches a fetch to my API that uses KOA and JWT. The javascript for the fetch initiated on click is:

```
<script>

        function loginButton(user, pass) {
            fetch('http://localhost:5454/api/login', {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: user,
                    password: pass
                })
            })
            .then( (response) => {
                console.log("Success")
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
        }

    </script>
```

The code for my Authentication is:

```
router.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, async (ctx) => {
const reqUsername = ctx.request.body.username
const reqPassword = ctx.request.body.password

const unauthorized = (ctx) => {
    ctx.status = 401
    ctx.body = {
        error: 'Invalid username or password'
    }
}

let attemptingUser
try {
    attemptingUser = await Employee.findOne({ where: { username: reqUsername }})
    if (attemptingUser != null && attemptingUser.password === reqPassword) {
        ctx.status = 200
        ctx.body = {
            username: attemptingUser.username,
            given_name: attemptingUser.given_name,
            role: attemptingUser.role,
            created_at: attemptingUser.createdAt,
            updated_at: attemptingUser.updatedAt,
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({ username: attemptingUser.username, role: attemptingUser.role }, SECRET)
        ctx.set("X-Auth", token)
    } else {
        unauthorized(ctx)
    }

} catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
    console.error(`Failed to find username: ${reqUsername}`)
    unauthorized(ctx)
}
```

})

The code for my KOA initiation is:

```
    require('dotenv').config()
const Koa = require('koa')
const Router = require('koa-router')
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')
const baseRoutes = require('./routes')
const cors = require('@koa/cors');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

const app = new Koa()


app.use(bodyParser())
app.use(baseRoutes.routes())
app.use(cors());

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`)
})
```

Im using Port 8080 for my http-server and port 5454 for my npm server. I am getting a Failed to Fetch in the catch of the Fetch, as well as a CORS error related to not having a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response header. I've tried a couple things and am ready to have a new set of eyes look at it, any tips?

Edit: I am successfully receiving the token in the X-Auth header, but for some reason it’s still throwing errors and I’d like to get them resolved before it spirals out of control.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the cors middleware?  E.g. does it work if you specify '*' as the `origin`?  How about if you specify `http://localhost:8080` for the origin?

Comment: Side note: You really should not be storing passwords in plain text: you should us a library to hash, salt, and pepper them.  Nor should you compare passwords (or password hashes) with `===` because it leaves you open to timing attacks.  And further, sending a JWT to the client leaves you up to a number of attacks, but most obviously XSS.  And (!) your error messages allow attackers to enumerate usernames.